# ActionLink behaving odd in ASP.Net MVC 2 Preview 2

Tags: model-view-controller, actionlink

This action link:

```
 <%=Html.ActionLink("About","About", "Home" ,new  { @class="menulink" }) %>
```

Produces the following href 'About?Length=4'  so it works in the 'root' of the application, but does not once you go one level or more deeper.  Also...why is the '?Length=4' being appended? Lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go it...my parameters are out of order and missing a null RouteValueDictionary...should be:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("About","About", "Home" ,null,new  { @class="menulink" }) %>
```